# Maven site multi module - folder generation issue

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I am trying to build a site for a multi-module projects.
My workspace is like this :

```
+- application
|   +-  app1
|   |    +-- pom.xml
|   +-  app2
|        +-- pom.xml
+- interface
|   +-  interf1
|   |    +-- pom.xml
|   +-  interf2
|        +-- pom.xml
+- logic
|   +-  logic1
|   |    +-- pom.xml
|   +-  logic2
|        +-- pom.xml
+-- pom.xml (parent one)
```

I wanted to build a staged site of this project.
It works if I stay at level 0 (root), but I cannot navigate into the child modules because they are not in the correct folder.

What is created in the filesystem:

```
stage
+- index.html                              <- A
+- dependencies.html 
+- (...)
+-- application
|    +-- app1
|    |     +-- index.html 
|    |     +-- dependencies.html
|    +-- app2
|          +-- index.html 
|          +-- dependencies.html
(and so on...)
```

What is in the code of "`A`" :

```
<a href="app1/index.html" ..>
```

instead of

```
<a href="applications/app1/index.html" ..>
```

I don't want to change my project structure. Is there a way to indicate Maven to preserve the folder structure when creating the staged site ?

I am using Maven 3.0.4 and maven-site-plugin 3.0.

parent pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <stagingDirectory>/home/me/stage</stagingDirectory>
        <reportPlugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </reportPlugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you use the most recent version of the site plugin?  I think it's up to at least 3.3.

Comment: Also the maven-project-info-repository-plugin there is a newer version available (2.7) see here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: @user944849 it works, indeed ! Last version is 3.4, edited on July this year ! Please post an answer, so I will be able to ack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the most recent version of the site plugin (3.4).